# Red5 NetConnection Rejected

Tags: flash, connection, red5

I wrote a simple application in Flash Builder supposed to work in the red5 server... However when i run the application the red5 server rejects the connection.... The event.info.code says "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected"...

I've tried changing Red5 versions (I've used version 0.6, 0.8 and 0.9) however nothing seems to work.. I've googled the error but it shows up no results...

Red5 installer doesnt seem to be able to connect to its server either.. It shows "NetConnection.Connect.Failed"... The logs show the following lines

```
2011-04-21 22:08:02,469 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.a.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter - W3C x-category:session x-event:connect c-ip:127.0.0.1 c-client-id:0

2011-04-21 22:08:02,479 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.a.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter - W3C x-category:session x-event:disconnect c-ip:127.0.0.1 c-client-id:0
```

I've been stuck at this for a long time and can find no way out... I need to build a Flash application and cannot use Flash Media Server due to its cost...

My code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
            import flash.net.NetConnection;
            import flash.net.ObjectEncoding;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            [Bindable]
            private var nc:NetConnection;

            public function init():void
            {
                writeText("init()");    
                nc=new NetConnection();
                    nc.objectEncoding=ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
                    writeText("init()");
                    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatus);

                    writeText("init()");
                    nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/first",true);
                    writeText("init()");
                }

                private function netStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
                {
                    writeText("netstatus()");
                    writeText(event.info.code);
                    trace(event.info.code);
                    if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected")
                    {
                        Alert.show("Rejected madarchod");
                        writeText("reject");
                        trace(event.info.application);
                    }
                    if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
                    {
                        writeText("connect");
                    }
                }

            private function writeText(txt:String):void
            {
                txtHistory.text+=txt+"\n";
            }




        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea top="10" bottom="10" id="txtHistory" width="252" height="10" />


</s:Application>
```

Comment: Please make sure, that your server is up and running, and specify the correct port in your url: `rtmp://localhost/first`. Also check if your application is deployed/recognized with the name `first`. You can check test connecting to your application using the oflaDemo (it can be very handy!). If rtmp doesn't work, try with rtmpt as well, and make sure that you're using the right ports for those protocols.

Comment: I would also recomment to check if you have "first" app installed on your server. Also check http://localhost:5080/ if you see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had strange errors like this when my own application was compiled with java7 but the server runs on java6. No errors on startup but connection allways rejected. You should really use the oflaDemo to be shure that the client works. With own applications you can make a lot of mistakes.